# Table Structure for Storing multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables says, `val_taxes` and `val_tax_groups` the first table has all the tax separately like so

val_taxes

```
| id | tax_name | tax_value |
-----------------------------
| 1  | sgst     | 2.4       |
| 2  | cgst     | 2.4       |
| 3  | service  | 2.4       |
```

val_tax_groups

```
| id | tax_group_name |
-----------------------
| 1  | group_1        |
| 1  | group_2        |
```

The question is that, how do I connect these two tables? Should I add a foreign key in the `val_taxes` table or in `val_tax_groups` table?

I don't want to use comma separated values. If I introduce a foreign key in `val_tax_groups` then it might have duplicate `tax_group_name` as any val_taxes can be associated with any val_tax_groups.

For example; `sgst` could be present in group1 as well as group2, this will create a duplicate? How can I overcome this?

Comment: What is the meaning of val_tax_group.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any val_taxes can be associated with any val_tax_groups

It sounds like you have a many-to-many relationship.  You'll need a new table with which to join these two.  I agree with Lennart that you should use more explicit names rather than just "ID".  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TaxGroupMemberships
(
TaxID       INT NOT NULL REFERENCES val_taxes (TaxID)
TaxGroupID  INT NOT NULL REFERENCES val_tax_groups (TaxGroupID),
PRIMARY KEY (TaxID, TaxGroupID),
UNIQUE (TaxGroupID, TaxID)
)
```

My MySQL DDL skills are very rusty, so apologies if this syntax isn't perfect.

Note that the `UNIQUE` constraint isn't necessary for data integrity, it's just an optimization for when you run queries against `TaxGroupMemberships.TaxGroupID`.

Also note that taxes can change.  If you'd like to be flexible, you should add a `DateEffective` field, and include it in both constraints, so you can query "what taxes were in which groups as of date X?"

Answer (score 1):

First, let's name the columns properly:

```
CREATE TABLE val_taxes
( tax_id ...
, ...
);

CREATE TABLE val_tax_groups
( tax_group_id ...
, ...
);
```

Now, I assume that a `val_tax` belongs to a `val_tax_group`, so we need an attribute for that:

```
CREATE TABLE val_taxes
( tax_id ...
, ...
, tax_group_id ...
);
```

It is now possible to add a foreign key in `val_taxes` as:

```
ALTER TABLE val_taxes ADD CONSTRAINT ...
    FOREIGN KEY (tax_group_id)
    REFERENCES val_tax_groups (tax_group_id)
```

or have it directly in the table definition